# Determine source of 'onscroll' event

Tags: javascript, events, browser, onscroll

I have a listener for the 'onscroll' event of window. In that handler I need to somehow figure out what triggered the event, e.g. I am running an animation which triggers window.scrollTo(x, y) and the listener should have different behaviour, if the event was triggered by the animation. More precisely, in case the user scrolls while the animation is running, I have to stop the animation. Is it even possible to pass a context to the event handler when I trigger window.scrollTo(x, y) or is there some hacky workaround to achieve this?

Here is some pseudo code of what I am trying to achieve:

```
let isAnimationRunning = false

function onScrollHandler(e) {
  const isTriggeredByOnAnimationTick = // how to figure that one out???

  if (isAnimationRunning && !isTriggeredByOnAnimationTick) {
    stopAnimation()
  }
  // do something else
}

// called every key frame (requestAnimationFrame)
function onAnimationTick(scrollY) {
  // will trigger onscroll handler at some point in time
  window.scrollTo(0, scrollY)
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', onScrollHandler)

runAnimation(onAnimationTick)
```

I already thought about using different handlers for mousewheel and touch events on mobile. However, with that approach I encountered two problems:

1. One has to come up with another hack to figure out, whether the user scrolls via scrollbar
2. On mobile devices scrolling is decelerated after the touch gesture ends, thus I can not really figure out when the scroll event stops without using the onscoll handler.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of detecting the users scroll we could rather check the position to the one we wanted to land at. If that changes the user has probably scrolled:

```
function scroll(x,y,end,interrupt,requireX, requireY){
  //the movement applied after each loop
  const speedX = 1, speedY = 1;

  //check if the scrolled amount is not what we expect
  if(requireX && requireX !== scrollX || 
      requireY && requireY !== scrollY ) return interrupt();

  //check if we reached our position
  if( Math.abs(x - scrollX) < speedX && 
       Math.abs(y - scrollY) < speedY
   )  return end();

   //now finally scroll using window.scrollBy
   scrollBy(
      x > scrollX ? speedX : -speedX,
      y > scrollY ? speedY : -speedY
   );

   //next iteration in 10ms  
   setTimeout(scroll, 10, x, y, end, interrupt,scrollX, scrollY) ;
}
```

The whole thing is then usable as:

```
scroll(
  1000, //x to scroll to
  0, //y to scroll to
  _=>alert("finish"), //end handler
  _=>alert("interrupt") //user interrupted handler
);
```

[Try it](http://jsbin.com/yaxafixage/edit?output)